# Does Windows 10 have new features that improve performance as a guest OS in a VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-10

Are there any features that were added to Windows 10 that directly improve performance (and possibly interoperability) when run as a guest in a virtual machine? If so, are these features enabled by default, when a virtual environment is detected?

Note: This is for features in the OS itself, not to any specific virtual host additions, tools, etc

Answer (score -1):

Last week, I have upgraded both my desktop(i7, 16Gb) and laptop(i7, 8Gb) to win10.  The upgrade broke both VirtualBox and VMware Player.  An uninstall and reinstall worked for VM Player, but VBox still had issues recognizing any of my network interfaces.  Had to replace VBox 4.x with VBox 5.x and it worked fine.

As to the performance, I haven't noticed any significant differences between the VMs running on win8 vs. win10.  However, this comparison is done with a staight 'out of the box' upgrade with no system tweaks or configuration changes.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I specifically asked about its performance as a Guest OS, and specific features added to improve it's operability as a guest. Your entire answer is about having Windows 10 as the Host OS.

Comment: And I stated that I didn't see any performance changes with the VMs (guests) and not aware of any specific features.  I thought the other information would be useful for someone who was considering upgrading to win10, but sorry to wast your time.